# Why for_each requires an instance to be passed as an argument while the hash unary function for unordered map does not in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, functor, unordered-map

To construct an unordered map with a customized hash function

```
struct EnumClassHash
{
    template <typename T>
    std::size_t operator()(T t) const
    {
    return static_cast<std::size_t>(t);
    }
};

enum class MyEnum {};

std::unordered_map<MyEnum, int, EnumClassHash> myMap;
```

To construct a `for_each` function

```
struct Class
{ 
    void operator() (int a) 
    { 
        cout << a * 3 << " "; 
    } 
};

for_each(arr, arr + 5, Class()); 

// or equivalently
Class ob;
for_each(arr, arr + 5, ob);
```

why does `for_each` require an instance to be passed while an unordered map's hasher can take a class directly (EnumClassHash vs Class() / ob)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
std::unordered_map<MyEnum, int, EnumClassHash>
```

you are specifying a *type*. When you write

```
for_each(arr, arr + 5, Class());
```

you are specifying an *expression*. These are two very different things.

Answer (score 4):

`std::unordered_map` does actually have an overloaded constructor that takes an instance of the comparator as a parameter, if you wish to provide one. Otherwise `std::unordered_map` default-constructs the comparator. It can do that because it knows what the comparator class is, it's given right there, in the template.

On the other hand, where do you think `std::for_each` could possibly get the [`UnaryFunction` class instance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), if it's not passed explicitly as its third parameter? Let's say you have this example:

```
std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end());
```

How would this `std::for_each` know what'll gobble up the sequence? I suppose that the container's class could be made an explicit template parameter for `std::for_each`, but that unnecessarily complicates the interface and doesn't really add much value.

Comment: So why does for_each needs Struct/Class to be passed as an instance (Class() or ob as in the example) while the hasher of the unordered map can just take EnumClassHash directly?

Comment: I explained this is the 2nd paragraph, and the last sentence of the first paragraph in my answer, respectively. What, specifically, in my answer is unclear to you?

Comment: `std::for_each` *could* have been written with a default argument, such that `std::for_each<decltype(container.begin()), UnaryFunction>(container.begin(), container.end());` would default construct a `UnaryFunction`, but it isn't, and even if it were, `std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), UnaryFunction{});` is neater

Comment: @Caleth: Presumably we'd have switched the template parameters in that case, so you could just write `std::for_each<UnaryFunction>(...)`.